# Error from Mongrel: "HTTP element REQUEST_PATH is longer than the 1024 allowed length"

Tags: ruby, http, mongrel

I have a website that runs queries on the server, which is running Mongrel.  The query syntax can get quite involved, and I just ran a query (HTTP request) that yielded this error.

All workarounds welcome.

EDIT: Here's the full ajax command:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:    '/parsequery/' + jsonQuery,
        beforeSend: function(x) { // this is needed because otherwise jquery doesn't see the returned data as json
            if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                x.overrideMimeType("text/html");
            }
        },
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            if (parsedOK(data)) {
                executeQuery(jsonQuery);
            }
            else {
                handleFailedParse(data);
            }

        },
        error:  function(jaXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error sending request: " + textStatus)
        }

    });
```

Comment: `beforeSend` should not be necessary.  I think you just need to change `datatype: 'json'` to `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use HTTP POST for that.  Many server and browser implementations have tight limits on the query length, something around 1 kByte or 2 kBytes.

So instead of

```
<form action="http://www.example.org/foo" method="get">
```

you should do

```
<form action="http://www.example.org/foo" method="post">
```

And in case you do not do the requests via forms, you could use jQuery for instance:

```
$.post("/foo", {"param1": "foo", "param2": "bar"}, function(data) {
  alert("post successful!");
});
```

See here for examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Of course the server side needs to handle POST requests.  But changing from GET to POST on the server side is should be from a programming point of view trivial.

Comment: Ok, can you give more details how the post request is fired?  And how do you supply the parameters?  Even with post the parameters may be transmitted through the 'get part', i.e. through the URL and not through the body.

Comment: I just added the ajax command I'm using to my original post.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem with the query above is this: you explicitely paste it into the URL, so the URL part gets really long.  What you should do instead: transform `/parsequery/foo/bar?param1=abc&param2=def` into `$.ajax(url: "/parsequery/foo/bar", ..., data: {param1: "abc", param2: "def"}, ...)`.  This way the parameters are transferred via the http body and you actually make use of the big send payload of the POST request.